# iPhone App Store Release Question!

Tags: iphone, app-store, release

I am developing an Application its purpose to view uploaded files on a host server, and it has a credentials that will be entered on the Login Page to authenticate the user.

My Question! when I post my application to the App Store how suppose apple is going to test or at least view my application when Apple needs enter a valid credentials that I am not suppose to know, it's private to my client.

Any guide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, not a programming question. Second: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: if you're correct where do you think the best place to ask this? and i see it's a programming question! because maybe in my case i need to develop a Demo Web service to let Apple test my application? is not that programming enough?

Comment: Programmers.stackexchange.com - Place for more subjective questions.

Comment: to be honest i am shocked, telling me this is a subjective Question! i have seen Many Question like my question here over StackOverFlow, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973275/what-is-the-best-book-for-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you test your application yourself?
There is an extra field to give the Appstore people some hints / explanation. Generally, you'd use that field to give them a demo account on the server so they can the app.

Comment: i am testing it on a Local Server, my client have his own server and i don't think he will be accepting the idea of given me any of his Credentials, building a new web service for the App Store will be expensive, don't you think so?

Comment: If your client won't give you (or Apple) a test account and you can't or won't build a new web service you're kind of stuck. Apple likely won't approve an app it can't test.

Comment: So make your local test server available for testing - but seriously, how can you yourself actually make sure the app works if you haven't tested in on the production server?